# Unable to read Data from the Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here is the structure of my Firebase database.
[image: Database Image]

Recently I changed the name inside each tank in firebase from `lev` to `level` as in the image. Now the `ref.on` is not working with the database. I have added `console.log("passed");` inside `ref`, and even that is not getting printed. The function `setvalues` is called but ref inside it is not working. What is the problem here?

```
<head>      
   <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.8.1/firebase.js"></script>
</head>
<body >
<script type="text/javascript">
      var firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: "xx",
      authDomain: "xxx.firebaseapp.com",
      databaseURL: "https://xxx.firebaseio.com",
      projectId: "xxx",
      storageBucket: "xxx.appspot.com",
      messagingSenderId: "xxxx",
      appId: "xxx:xxx:web:xxx",
      measurementId: "xxx"
      };

     firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
      var ref1 = firebase.database().ref('tank01/');
      var tank1;

    function setvalues(callback){

      ref1.on("value", function(snapshot) {
      console.log("Passed");
      tank1 = snapshot.val()['level'];
      callback();
       }); 

    }

    setvalues(function(data){
        console.log("set");
    });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your realtime database rules are restricted to only authorized users to perform read and write operations.  Check your database rules again.  If you are getting the same problem change your rules to public access.

It should be like this

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

Hope this helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

Check this,I have changed a little bit.

This will work because i changed to public so that all app can interact with realtime database.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write":true,
    "users": {
      ".read": true,
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "auth.uid === $uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```